# Horizontally align text with a DIV

Tags: html, css

There are a few questions on Stackoverflow which ask about aligning elements horizontally using CSS (divs).  Generally, this is accomplished using floats, or `display: inline-block`.

However, I have a pretty simple requirement, and I'm having difficulty using either of these techniques to get it to work perfectly.  I simply want to horizontally align a line of text with a DIV element.

So, basically, there are 3 ways of doing this:

**Method 1 (Using `display: inline-block`)**

```
<div style = "display: inline-block;">Foo</div>
<div style = "display: inline-block; padding-left: 19px">
    <div style = "border: 1px solid #000000; height: 1em; width: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

**Method 2 (Using `float`)**

```
<div style = "width: 150px">
    <div style = "float:left">Foo</div>
    <div style = "float:right">
        <div style = "border: 1px solid #000000; height: 1em; width: 100px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 3** using.. (please don't kill me) a `<table>`:

```
<table style = "width: 150px" cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0" border = "0">
    <tr>
        <td style = "width: 40px">
            Foo
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style = "border: 1px solid #000000; height: 1em; width: 100px"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

These three methods render like this on Firefox:

[image]

Okay, so firstly, the problem with Method 1 (`inline-block`) is that the text isn't vertically aligned (centered) with the DIV element, which looks awkward.  Instead, the bottom border of the DIV is aligned with the bottom of the text.  I tried adjusting padding and margins to fix this, but it didn't help.

Method 2 (`float`s) looks good, but the problem with Method 2 is what happens if the text changes to something longer?  Well...

[image]

So the problem with using floats is that if the text gets longer, the DIV element is knocked down to the next line.  So this isn't acceptable.  Note that Method 1 (`inline-block`) doesn't have this problem.

The only method which meets all requirements is the one which uses a `<table>`, but I don't want to use that, because ... well, [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).

So, what's the best solution here.  How can I use just DIVs with CSS to get the same result as Method 3, which uses a `<table>`?

Comment: No spans, indenting, margins, nor javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `line-height:1em; vertical-align:top;` to the text containing div of method 1 seems to solve this (where line-height is the height of the bordered div).

I, myself, prefer `inline-block` to `float` due to the unpredictability of `float` in earlier versions of IE. It is also hard to prevent the `float` overflowing to the next line as this is what it was designed for, really!